# iPhone 4s and 5 Safari - URL Bar + Toolbar Minimize and Cause Problems Comparing Scroll Top and Element Offset

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone

When scrolling a webpage on iPhone 4S or 5 on Safari the URL bar and the toolbar at the bottom minimize.

I have encountered an issue when I try to check if the top offset of a given element is visible while scrolling.

Please see the following test http://paolodipasquale.co.uk/tests/iphone-safari-window-height/ on an iPhone 4S or 5 (although other versions running OS 8 will probably also have this issue).

Notice that when you scroll down the page at a certain point the div above the footer becomes red.

If you consider the following code:

```
var $window = $(window),
    $divAboveFooter = $('.divAboveFooter'),
    footerOffset = $('footer').offset().top;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() + $window.height() >= footerOffset) {
            $divAboveFooter.addClass('red');
        } else {
            $divAboveFooter.removeClass('red');
        }
    });
```

You would assume that the div would turn red as soon as the footer comes into view. In fact if you view the page on a desktop browser and resize the browser window you will find it works as expected.

I think this is happening because of the URL bar and toolbar minimizing when the page is scrolled but I am struggling to come up with a solution apart from subtracting a few pixels from the footer offset if the page is being viewed on Safari and on an iPhone, however, I appreciate this is prone to error so I would like to avoid this if possible.

Would be grateful if someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: I have found that when the URL and Toolbar are minimized a window resize event is triggered, however, if you calculate the height using `$(window).height()` you still get the same value as before they were minimized.

Comment: Unfortunately the window resize event is not triggered on iOS 7. On iOS8 you can however get the correct window height using `window.innerHeight`